# How to upload a temporary tile on front end and view on its browser html div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I want to upload a temporary text file say '.json' file on front end.

Then view it in a div element of current window html.

say html body has two div

left div have a form with a upload button to upload a file
and right div displays the content of file after uploading the file

I DO NOT WANT TO MAKE ANY REQUEST TO ANY SERVER.
all i want a front end script to upload a file and display within its tab window

Is that possible? How?

Comment: Google -> MDN Filereader

Comment: The word 'upload' implies sending data from the client to the server. However, if you use an input element with the type set to file _and_ you use a FileReader object, you _can_ allow the user to select a file, which you then preview, without the use of a server. See here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body>
    <input id="File" type="file" />
    <input id="Button" type="button" value="button" />
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
        var input = document.getElementById('File');
        var button = document.getElementById('Button');
        var container = document.getElementById('container');
        button.onclick = function () {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function () {
                container.innerHTML = reader.result;
            }
            input.files.length > 0 && reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

### [*Demo Fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/K5qV7/1/embedded/result/)

*Javascript*

```
var files = evt.target.files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (function () {
    return function (e) {
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = e.target.result;
        document.getElementById('output').appendChild(span);
    };
})(files);
reader.readAsText(files);
```

References:
1. [HTML5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)
2. [Firefox MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

[Check the browser support for FileApi](http://caniuse.com/#search=file%20api)
**Limitation: This code can show only those files which can be `readAsText`**

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that uses `FileReader.readAsBinaryString`.
It comes from an app that allows offline modification of images via the canvas element, without using a server. I find that graphics algorithms are much faster to prototype in JS than C/ASM - platform independence and zero compile-time.

Usually, one has to grab an image from a server (either localhost or a remote one) in order to get past the SameOrigin policy.

Error checking is minimal - i.e, you can select a text/video/whatever file and the code will still attempt to load it and set its contents to be the data used to construct a dataURI for an image element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded()
{
    byId('mFileInput').addEventListener('change', onFileChosen, false);
}

// fileVar is an object as returned by <input type='file'>
// imgElem is an <img> element - can be on/off screen (doesn't need to be added to the DOM)
function loadImgFromFile(fileVar, imgElem)
{
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = onFileLoaded;
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(fileVar);
    function onFileLoaded(fileLoadedEvent)
    {
        var result,data;
        data = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        result = "data:";
        result += fileVar.type;
        result += ";base64,";
        result += btoa(data);
        imgElem.src = result;
        imgElem.origType = fileVar.type;    // unnecessary for loading the image, used by a current project.
    }
}

function onFileChosen(evt)
{
    if (this.files.length != 0)
    {
        var tgtImg = byId('tgt');
        var curFile = this.files[0];
        loadImgFromFile(curFile, tgtImg);
    }
}

</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <input id='mFileInput' type='file'/><br>
    <img id='tgt' />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IE 10 and 11 do not know anything about readAsBinaryString(), is better to use readAsDataURL().. Because you still converting Binary string to base64 manually

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize that IE still deserves the mispronounced name of InternetExploder. I suppose that I could still try `atob` on the result in the event that I actually do want binary data.